# URL Rewrite PHP still get the same $_GET['']?

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I am very noob to this URL rewrite. just got a question in my head.

**www.example.com/?page_name=home**

The $_GET['page_name'] is actually home

after the URL rewrite the url become

**www.example.com/home**

can PHP still get the $_GET['page_name'] is 'home'??

Thanks

Comment: yes.. it is the same result as the above

Comment: Shouldn't that be the other way around? you want to internally rewrite `/home` to `/?page_name=home`.

Comment: The question is a bit vague. What url rewriting do you have?

Comment: @Jack I want www.example.com/home to read out /?page_name=home which you have correctly pointed out. just a quick one, to achieve this, u need to use Apache URL rewrite mod right?

Comment: @bluebill1049 that's right, apache mod_rewrite will do that kind of stuff :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using rewriting like this (change it as per your need):

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?page_name=$1 [L]
```

Above rule redirects

```
http://www.domain.com/string_LiKe-this53/
```

on a real existing page

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=string_LiKe-this53
```

on which you can use your `$_GET['page']`, which will have value `string_LiKe-this53`.

Comment: so this will interrupt /anything (include /test/test/test)? interrupt to /index.php?page_name=test/test/test?

Answer (score 2):

The URL rewriting is done by the *web server*, let's say in this case Apache. This is not the same as PHP.

Apache receives a request for the URL `www.example.com/home`. It now needs to figure out what to do with this request. It will check its configuration for something that matches `www.example.com`, which will point it to a *document root*, i.e. some folder on the hard disk. It checks that folder on the hard disk and encounters an .htaccess file. It evaluates the .htaccess file, which tells it to *rewrite* the URL from `/home` to `?page_name=home`.

Apache now tries to figure out what to do with `?page_name=home`. Since there's no filename given, it defaults to `index.php` (which hopefully exists). It now runs that `index.php` file in the document root, passing it `?page_name=home` as the URL it has received. PHP takes it from there, oblivious of the rewriting that happened. To PHP, it appears that you have received the parameter `page_name` as query parameter and puts it in `$_GET`.

Comment: Wow so well explained. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the rewrite rule, but yes, you can get it to work as intended.

The following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule /home /index.php?page_name=home
```

Will simply cause requests to /home to execute index.php with `$_GET['page_name']` equal to "home".

Depending on the complexity of your site, however, it may be preferable to use a more generic rewrite rule, such as:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1
```

Then you would query $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] to see if it contained "home". This will play nicely with other $_GET parameters that may be passed in.

Comment: What about /anything interrupt to /index.php?page_name=anything?

Comment: See @Vishal's answer for that.